# What is wrong with this assignment in a conditional operator?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, variable-assignment, conditional-operator, lvalue

There is an error.
Is it wrong to assign a value to a[i] in the following code?
Or something is wrong with conditional operators?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
  char a[12]="sumit tyagi";
  int i=0;
  while(a[i]!='\0'){ 
  a[i]>90 ? a[i]=a[i]-32 : a[i]=a[i]+32; //error in this line
  i++;
  } 
  printf("\n %s",a);
```

Comment: You might have a problem with operator precedence. The way you use `?:`is a bit weird. You would probably be better off, using a plain `ìf ... else...` statement

Comment: `a[i] = a[i]>90 ? a[i]-32 : a[i]+32;`

Comment: Don't abuse the ternary operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a[i]>90 ? a[i]=a[i]-32 : a[i]=a[i]+32;`

is **not** evaluated as

`a[i]>90 ? (a[i]=a[i]-32) : (a[i]=a[i]+32);`

since `=` has lower precedence than `?:`. In standard C you can't write it as above although some compilers allow it as an extension.

You could write it as the more readable (and portable)

```
a[i] += a[i] > 90 ? -32 : +32;
```

Comment: Well gosh, now you left me hanging. :) Was it intentionally wrong or just an accidental mistake made while refining it? (the edit history seems to show a different expression originally) If it was intended as a joke, I'll have to apologize: I'm not used to seeing unmarked sarcasm on SE, possibly because the poor novices might learn bad things from it.

Comment: @ilkkachu: On a second glance, the expression looks incorrect, and looks like it can be negative. I think I'll tin it, with thanks to you!

Comment: I think that may be a good idea. And thank you, I feel more at peace already! :)

Answer (score 4):

This is really a matter of understanding the syntax of the [conditional operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15). This is spelled out in §6.5.15 of the C11 Standard:

> *conditional-expression:*
>   *logical-OR-expression*
>   *logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression*

Thus, the third operand to the conditional operator must be a *conditional-expression*. Tracing the possibilities for conditional expressions through the grammar defined in the Standard, one finds that an assignment expression is not one of the options. The relevant syntax definitions are found in [§6.5 Expressions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5).

By following the chain of possibilities from *conditional-expression* all the way back to *primary-expression*, it can be seen that a *conditional-expression* may be a *logical-OR-expression*, or a *logical-AND-expression*, or an *inclusive-OR-expression*, or an *exclusive-OR-expression*, or an *AND-expression*, or an *equality-expression*, or a *relational-expression*, or a *shift-expression*, or an *additive-expression*, or a *multiplicative expression*, or a *cast-expression*, or a *unary-expression*, or a *postfix-expression*, or a *primary-expression*. A *primary-expression* is an *identifier*, a *constant*, a *string-literal*, an *( expression )*, or a *generic-selection*.

So, an [*assignment-expression*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16) (which *may* be a conditional expression) is not on the list of possibilities for a conditional expression. This is the reason for the error reported in the question: since an assignment expression is not valid syntax here, the statement:

```
a[i]>90 ? a[i]=a[i]-32 : a[i]=a[i]+32;
```

is interpreted as:

```
(a[i]>90 ? a[i]=a[i]-32 : a[i]) = a[i]+32;
```

The left side of the above assignment expression is not a modifiable lvalue, as required for an assignment expression, hence the error.

But, note that a parenthesized expression of the form **( *expression* )** *is* a valid *conditional-expression*, and an *assignment-expression* is an *expression*. So, this is a legal statement:

```
a[i]>90 ? a[i]=a[i]-32 : (a[i]=a[i]+32);
```

All of that said, this is probably not the right way to code this. Better to use one of the alternatives proposed in other answers, such as:

```
a[i] += a[i] > 90 ? -32 : 32;
```

Comment: This is indeed correct. I'll try to update my answer to be correct as well, still using the cppreference.com citation ...

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit tricky. There's a nice overview of "*effective*" [operator precedence in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and I'll cite the notes from there explaining your problem *):

> There is a part of the grammar that cannot be represented by a precedence table: an assignment-expression is not allowed as the right hand operand of a conditional operator, so `e = a < d ? a++ : a = d` is an expression that cannot be parsed, and therefore relative precedence of conditional and assignment operators cannot be described easily.
>   However, many C compilers use non-standard expression grammar where `?:` is designated higher precedence than `=`, which parses that expression as `e = ( ((a < d) ? (a++) : a) = d )`, which then fails to compile due to semantic constraints: `?:` is never *lvalue* and `=` requires a modifiable *lvalue* on the left.

After DavidBowling's findings in the standard (thanks for this work!), the second paragraph above is not entirely correct, or, at least a bit confusing. It's correct that the right-hand operand of `?:` cannot be an assignment, but the middle operand can. So for the right-hand side, the `?:` "takes precedence" over `=`, while it doesn't for the middle part. Any part can be a *primary expression*, therefore paranthesizing to "change *precedence*" works as expected:

```
a[i]>90 ? a[i]=a[i]-32 : (a[i]=a[i]+32);
```

But, as others have stated, this is needlessly complex anyways, you can achieve what you want with just

```
a[i] += a[i]>90 ? -32 : 32;
```

which is also easier to understand.

---

*) To understand the reasoning in this citation, you have to know that *lvalue* is used in the C standard to describe something that might appear on the *left hand side* (hence the name) of an assignment (aka can be assigned to). This is a somewhat sloppy definition and is clarified further in the C standard, I think it's enough for the context of this answer.

Comment: Nice analysis of the theoretical evaluation and why compilation necessarily fails: you noticed I chickened out of doing that. Have an upvote.

Comment: Fortunately, I found a well-written source to cite the tricky part from ;)

Comment: Upvoted already because of the appeal to syntax; but further digging has revealed to me that `a[i]>90 ? (a[i]=a[i]-32) : (a[i]=a[i]+32);` is in fact legal. I have added an (hopefully correct) answer with the relevant details.

Comment: @DavidBowling it definitely *looks* correct at a first glance! I'll double-check myself with the standard, it would mean that cppreference.com is indeed missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=` once in your statement, since it has lower precedence over `?:`. Something like:

`a[i] = a[i] > 90 ? a[i] - 32 : a[i] + 32;`