# Understanding knapsack solution in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int p[20], w[20], kn[20][20], x[20], i, j, n, weight;
    Clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter the value of n ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter the price of the items ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &p[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter the weight of the items ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &w[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter the weight of the knapsack ");
    scanf("%d", &weight);
    printf("\nThe knapsack is ");
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j <= weight; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
                kn[i][j] = 0;
            } else
            if (w[i - 1] > j) {
                kn[i][j] = kn[i - 1][j];
            } else {
                kn[i][j] = (kn[i - 1][j] > (kn[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]] + p[i - 1])) ?
                            kn[i - 1][j] : (kn[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]] + p[i - 1]);
            }
            printf("%d ", kn[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nThe optimal solution is %d", kn[n][weight]);
    i = n;
    j = weight;
    while (i != 0) {
        if (kn[i][j] == kn[i - 1][j]) {
            x[i-1] = 0;
            i = i - 1;
        } else {
            x[i - 1] = 1;
            j = j - w[i - 1];
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nThe 0/1 knapsack is ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\nX[%d]=%d", i + 1, x[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Hey guys.. Well I am new to 'C' but I tried this knapsack problem from the textbook.  I really don't understand how it is working and especially not understanding this line
`kn[i][j]=(kn[i-1][j]>(kn[i-1][j-w[i-1]]+p[i-1]))?kn[i-1][j]:(kn[i-1][j-w[i-1]]+p[i-1]);`

Well, if anyone would like to explain please do...
Thank You so much:)

Comment: What do you need as explanation? The meaning of `?:`? The semantic of `kn[i][j]`? Since this is the only line you have problems with, I assume that the semantic of the array is clear to you.

Comment: Its ternary operator, google it. Simplify syntax of your command is `a = (b > c) ? d : e;`

Comment: If I did not misread anything the line can be simplyfied to `kn[i][j] = max(kn[i - 1][j], kn[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]] + p[i - 1]);`.

Comment: You don't understand it because it's 'clever code' with single-letter variable names and a one-line compound expression with the ternary operator and  multiple array indices.  It is, I'm afraid, bad code that is not designed to be understood, debugged or maintained.  Which textbook did you copy it from?  Do you have some gasoline and a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the idea that either you take the `i`-th item or not.

If you take the `i`-th item, then problem reduces to finding the optimal solution with `i-1` items and with a weight of knapsack `j-w[i]`.

If you don't take `i`-th item simply skip it. so the solution would be `kn[i-1][j]`.
Why `j`? Because you haven't taken any item so you can use the same weight for filling up in the knapsack.

Now you have this two choices and you select the one which gives you maximum fill up. That's why you need to find the maximum of this two.

That's what you do using the ternary operator.

Alternatively you can use the `max()` function to get the maximum of the two. Which will also result in the same answer.

Also you can use the ol' and simple `if-else`.

```
if( kn[i-1][j]>(kn[i-1][j-w[i-1]]+p[i-1]))
  kn[i][j]=kn[i-1][j];
else
  kn[i][j]=(kn[i-1][j-w[i-1]]+p[i-1]);
```

This ternary operator ultimately boils down to this `if-else`.

`j` is basically the weights we are considering. We are trying to solve the problem for smaller weights also. `j` signifies that. It is helpful in giving us the answer to the sub-problems.

Comment: ok.. learnin this.. but i came to know i,p,w value... but still wat the heck is j doin here?.

Comment: @ShashankMadan.; I have modiefied my answer...check it.

Answer (score 6):

This is the dynamic programming implementation of knapsack defined by two states weight and index. The sol above us built in a bottom-up manner meaning we start from one item initially and build our solution to n items considering the constraints which are cost maximum cost and weight.For the above problem i defines the index and j defines the weight.

**Thus kn[i][j] defines the maximum profit the problem setter can make by taking items from 0 to ith index having the capacity of the sack to be weight j.**

The approach to find the max value that can be obtained from n items is max of the below conditions

- Max value obtained by n-1 **(here i-1)** items and weight W **(here in each iteration j)**
- Include the value of the nth item + Max value obtained by n-1 items and weight W which includes the nth item weight.

I have included the reason for each stmt in comments.

Thus for each item, we can either include it in the sol or we cant.

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<=weight;j++)
        {
            if(i==0||j==0)     //if no of items to be included is 0 or max capacity is 0 the sol is 0
            {
                kn[i][j]=0;
            }
            else if(w[i-1]>j)   //if the nth item is greater than the weight j we can remove the item from our solution. 
            {  
                kn[i][j]=kn[i-1][j];
            }
            else
            {  //writing this cond in easier format
                kn[i][j]=max( val[i-1] + k[i-1][j-w[i-1]] , k[i-1][j])
            }
            printf("%d ",kn[i][j]);
        }
}
```

**Everyone has difficulty in 2nd & 3rd condition so for the sake of mankind lets take an example i=1. Thus knapsack has only 1 item which is represented by index i=0.**

**If the weight of this 0th item is greater than the max weight**(which is incremented in steps from 0 to weight w) we cant include this item. Thus for all j we have max value of knapsack as kn[1][j]= kn[i-1][j] i.e kn[0][j] which in turn is 0 since i=0 till we reach a stage where w[i-1]==j.

In easier english this means that max value that knapsack can hold with 1 item but with weight constraint less than that of item i-1 (here 0th item in array but actually 1st item) is 0 till j is incremented to a weight >= to this item represented by i=1(i.e 0th item in array).

**Else (As soon as weight represented by j is > item i-1 weight)**

(Now we have 2 conditions since although weight of this item is less than W or whatever j

1.If we include this item total weight of the previous included items and this current item (we are building sol bottom up) may exceed the total weight thus we dont want to include the item ) Knapsack value k[i][j]=k[i-1][j] previous included items only.

2. We can include this current item  thus K[i][j]= value of this ith item + max value obtained by i-1 items (for i=1 none here) which have a weight j- weight of current item.kn[i][j]=max( val[i-1] + k[i-1][j-w[i-1]] , k[i-1][j])

Thus i=1 we have a knapsack value as val[current item] + 0 (Since no previous items.)

The iteration goes on building solution bottom up.

)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

**That is ternary operator.**

If any operator is used on three operands or variable is known as **Ternary Operator**. It can be represented with ? : . **It is also called as conditional operator**

**Advantage of Ternary Operator:**

> Using ?: reduce the number of line codes and improve the performance
>   of application.

*Syntax:*

```
expression-1 ? expression-2 : expression-3
```

In the above symbol expression-1 is condition and expression-2 and expression-3 will be either value or variable or statement or any mathematical expression. If condition will be true expression-2 will be execute otherwise expression-3 will be executed.

For example:

```
a<b ? printf("a is less") : printf("a is greater");
```

Comment: Technically, according to the Standard, the syntax for the conditional operator is `logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression`. This distinction [can be significant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351186/6879826).